# How to send parsed URL values from javascript to src of img tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a html file called test.html.
Using JavaScript, I have parsed a URL to obtain the parsed parameters.

The URL looks something like this (Example URL)

```
http://path.to.a.webserver/test.html?p1=welcome&p2=home
```

After parsing the values, I want to send the parsed values to an HTML img tag in the following format. When I hit the above URL, the values p1 and p2 gets parsed and img tag in the test.html file gets executed.:

```
<img src="http://example2.com/tiger.gif?p1={p1_parsed_value}&p2={p2_parsed_value}"
```

I have tried using document.getElementById. I'm not sure if it is right. How can I pass only those parsed URL values into the src of the img tag?

Comment: take a look to [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Not clear what source of url is. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I have edited it. Is it clear now?

Comment: No, not really. Probably need to also read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var img = document.querySelector("img");//select node

img.setAttribute("src",url);//set src attribute to required url
```

Comment: I want to pass it directly to the src tag. Is there another method?

Comment: src is an **attribute** on img tag,

Comment: you may also take interest in jquery library, it makes dom traversal and manipulation easier

Answer (score 1):

you can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
var baseUrl = 'http://example2.com/tiger.gif';
var u = new URL('http://example.com/test.html?p1=welcome&p2=hello');

// u.search: ?p1=welcome&p2=hello
var newUrl = baseUrl  + u.search;
console.log(newUrl);

// or 
newUrl = baseUrl + '?p1=' + u.searchParams.get("p1") + '&p2=' + u.searchParams.get("p2")
console.log(newUrl);

//to display the image

document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="' + newUrl +'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test img').attr('src', function(index,`val`) {
    return val.replace("default.jpg", "dynamic.jpg");
});
```